# Convert dplyr::select structure to base R

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 10, expr = runif(n = 1000, min = 20, max = 100)
  )
)
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 |> 
(\(x) cbind(x, r = apply(x[colnames(x = select(x, where(is.numeric) & head(x = everything(x), 2) & starts_with("x.")))], 1, sum, na.rm = T)))()
```

I tried use `[` instead `colnames`, but doesn't work. I want convert this part (simultaneously, as a `dplyr::select` structure made above):

```
[colnames(x = select(x, where(is.numeric) & head(x = everything(x), 2) & starts_with("x.")))]
```

to base `R`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying not to use `dplyr`, just base R.

Comment: I've tried using `[`, `grep` and `Filter` but failing to do that in base R.

Comment: If you describe, what your code _should_ do, it would be easier to create a base R solution.

Comment: arent you just doing `cbind(df_1, r = rowSums(df_1[1:2]))`?? or even  `transform(df_1, r = x.1 + x.2)`

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
transform(df_1, r = x.1 + x.2)
```

or even:

```
cbind(df_1, r = rowSums(df_1[1:2]))
```

or even:

```
cbind(df_1, r = df_1[1] + df_1[2])
```